Deployment keeps failing .postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://<db_host>:<db_port>/<db_name>
This is my first time deploying a backend and db. Its a simple java/springboot app with postgres db I am doing it on render, I already deployed the postgres db on render (on port) 5432. And added all the connection info on my backend (like Hostname, port, database, username, password, xternal db url..),
The error I see in the lochs is :
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:40) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2024-10-30T13:36:57.394Z  WARN 1 --- [DVD-Library] [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: PostgreSQLDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
2024-10-30T13:37:07.090Z  INFO 1 --- [DVD-Library] [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-10-30T13:37:07.199Z  INFO 1 --- [DVD-Library] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-10-30T13:37:07.200Z  WARN 1 --- [DVD-Library] [           main] org.postgresql.util.PGPropertyUtil       : JDBC URL invalid port number: <db_port>
2024-10-30T13:37:07.294Z ERROR 1 --- [DVD-Library] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://<db_host>:<db_port>/<db_name>
2024-10-30T13:37:07.295Z  WARN 1 --- [DVD-Library] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://<db_host>:<db_port>/<db_name>
2024-10-30T13:37:07.297Z  INFO 1 --- [DVD-Library] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-10-30T13:37:07.397Z  INFO 1 --- [DVD-Library] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-10-30T13:37:07.692Z ERROR 1 --- [DVD-Library] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://<db_host>:<db_port>/<db_name>

Im setting these as environment variable in my application.properties and dockerfile. I pushed to the repo and build the docker "docker build -t dvd-library ."  and "docker run -e `
SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME=DVD-Library \
           -e DB_HOST=dpg-csgpnmogph6c73bqlvt0-a.virginia-postgres.render.com \
           -e DB_PORT=5432 \
           -e DB_NAME=dvdlibrarydb \
           -e DB_USERNAME=housseindev \
           -e DB_PASSWORD=****.. \
           -p 8080:8080 dvd-library"   but when i deploy it on render it keeps failing.

here is my application.properties :
spring.application.name=${SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME:DVD-Library}
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME:org.postgresql.Driver}
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=${SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL-AUTO:update}
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=${SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_DIALECT:org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect}
spring.config.use-legacy-processing=true


Here is my dockerfile:
# Use the official Maven image to build the application with Java 17
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17-slim AS build

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /Taskitory

# Copy the pom.xml and source code to the working directory
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src

# Package the application and skip tests
RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests=true

# Use a different OpenJDK image to run the application with Java 17
FROM openjdk:17-slim

# Set the working directory for the runtime container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the jar file from the build stage
COPY --from=build /Taskitory/target/*.jar app.jar

# Set environment variables for the database connection
ENV DB_HOST=dpg-csgpnmogph6c73bqlvt0-a.virginia-postgres.render.com
ENV DB_PORT=5432
ENV DB_NAME=dvdlibrarydb
ENV DB_USERNAME=housseindev
ENV DB_PASSWORD=dgrD8SGxkK9ssYnEv3kJBUBmoFsawsIJ
ENV SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME=org.postgresql.Driver
ENV SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL-AUTO=update
ENV SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_DIALECT=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
ENV SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME=DVD-Library

# Set the command to run the application
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]

Any help would be appriciated.

You seem to have defined the url not like you think you did, but the error shows jdbc:postgresql://<db_host>:<db_port>/<db_name>. Check if you defined it that way anywhere in your project

I had set “ jdbc:postgresql://<db_host>:<db_port>/<db_name>” as environment variables on my backend hosting..removed the enviroment variable and it worked. Thx for the input
